# wait(), notify() - For fast reading from file

Tags: java, filereader

I do not understand why my method of reading from a file on a line works so slowly.

Below is an example of my class. It gives a speed of 10MB / 14 sec.
At the same time, the main delays are caused by wait() and notify(). Why is this happening ?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class Reader {
    public static final String fileEnd = "=-=-=-=END=-=-=-=";


    private String nextLine;

    public Reader(File file){
        consume(file);
    }

    public String getLine(){
        String line;

        synchronized (this){
            while (true) {
                if(nextLine == null){
                    notify();


                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if(nextLine.equals(fileEnd)){
                    return fileEnd;
                }
                else {
                    line = nextLine;
                    nextLine = null;

                    notify();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return line;
    }

    private void consume(File file){
        Thread thread = new Thread(()->{
            final char c = System.getProperty("line.separator").charAt(0);
            try (RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")){

                FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10240);

                StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
                while (inChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
                    buffer.flip();


                    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
                        char as = (char) buffer.get();

                        if(as==c){
                            String compliteLine = line.toString();
                            line = new StringBuilder();

                            compliteLine = compliteLine.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "");


                            synchronized (this){
                                while (true) {
                                    if (nextLine == null) {
                                        nextLine = compliteLine;


                                        try {
                                            notify();
                                            wait();
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    } else {
                                        try {
                                            wait();
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        else {
                            line.append(as);
                        }

                    }

                    buffer.clear();
                }
                inChannel.close();

                synchronized (this){
                    notify();
                    wait();
                    nextLine = fileEnd;
                    notify();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ignored){ignored.printStackTrace();}
        });

        thread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPVS0.png)

I also tried to do the same on ArrayBlockingQueue with queue 100.
It takes a little less than a second to read the same file.
But this vseravno very slowly.
The code above I myself came up with in order to speed up the reading, but it happens even slower.

The question itself is why the code is higher, slower than the queue.
And how to accelerate it?

Comment: You've included a lot of code; to help others answer your question, consider creating a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve) to demonstrate your problem in a shorter format.

Comment: @ricky3350 what's this?

Comment: Bad link. Here's the right one: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Andreas, It's useless. All this code is required.

Comment: Setting a thread priority to max is usually a bad idea. Your code also seems rather complex, and you should really get out of the habit of ignoring exceptions (or not correctly handling them).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Why is the maximum priority for a thread a bad idea?
With exceptions, this is so - because this is a test version.

Comment: It is a bad idea, because it can lead to other threads not getting enough time to make progress, which can have all kinds of additional problems (your app not working as intended, resource cleanup issues, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.
I was rescued by LinkedTransferQueue.
It works exactly as I need it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue;

public class LinkedTransferQueueReader {
    public static final String fileEnd = "=-=-=-=END=-=-=-=";


    private LinkedTransferQueue<String> queue = new LinkedTransferQueue<>();


    public LinkedTransferQueueReader(File file){
        consume(file);
    }


    public String getLine(){
        String line = "";


        try {
            line = queue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return line;
    }

    private void consume(File file){
        Thread thread = new Thread(()->{
            final String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            final char r = lineSeparator.charAt(0);
            char n = '\0';
            if(lineSeparator.length() > 1)
                n = lineSeparator.charAt(1);

            try (RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")){

                FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10240);

                StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
                while (inChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
                    buffer.flip();


                    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
                        char as = (char) buffer.get();

                        if(as == n)
                            continue;
                        if(as==r){
                            String compliteLine = line.toString();
                            line = new StringBuilder();


                            queue.transfer(compliteLine);

                        }
                        else {
                            line.append(as);
                        }

                    }

                    buffer.clear();
                }
                inChannel.close();

                queue.transfer(fileEnd);
            }
            catch (Exception ignored){ignored.printStackTrace();}
        });

        thread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code above, the Thread blocks on every line read. Using an `ArrayBlockingQueue`, the Thread would only block if it had read 100 items from the File before those items were taken out of the queue. Depending on how quick the processing is that's taking items out of the queue, it may never block.

If you want to make the code above faster, you could look into having more than one buffer so that the Thread doesn't need to block every line. Essentially, you'd be implementing a `BlockingQueue` yourself.